# KMM + Compose: Unresolved reference: drawable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a KMM application in which the android target uses Jetpack Compose. I am getting the following error when I try to use a drawable resource:

> e: [...]/OnboardingScreen.kt: (33, 46): Unresolved reference: drawable

This is the result of trying to access a drawable via `painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon)`.

I have tried the following things to fix the issue:

- Clean and build the project
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Fix all warnings when executing `./gradlew assembleDebug`
- The static R class is correctly imported

Nothing of the above solves the problem.

This is my build.gradle.kts of the android module:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
}

val composeVersion = findProperty("version.compose") as String
val composeNavigationVersion = findProperty("version.composeNavigation") as String
val koinVersion = findProperty("version.koin") as String

android {

    compileSdk = (findProperty("android.compileSdk") as String).toInt()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.app.app.android"
        minSdk = (findProperty("android.minSdk") as String).toInt()
        targetSdk = (findProperty("android.targetSdk") as String).toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    // Set both the Java and Kotlin compilers to target Java 8.
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = composeVersion
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(project(":shared"))

    // Android
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")

    // Jetpack Compose
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$composeNavigationVersion")

    // Koin
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koinVersion")
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.31")
    }
}
```

My build.gradle.kts of the shared module:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64() // sure all ios dependencies support this target

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../ios/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    val multiplatformVersion = findProperty("version.multiplatformSettings") as String
    val koinVersion = findProperty("version.koin") as String
    val coroutinesVersion = findProperty("version.coroutines") as String
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings-no-arg:$multiplatformVersion")
                implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 22
        targetSdk = 31
    }
}
```

And finally, my gradle.properties:

```
# Gradle
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx2048M"

# Kotlin
kotlin.code.style=official

# Android
android.useAndroidX=true
android.compileSdk=31
android.targetSdk=31
android.minSdk=22

# MPP
kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata=true
kotlin.mpp.enableCInteropCommonization=true
kotlin.native.enableDependencyPropagation=false
kotlin.native.ignoreDisabledTargets=true

# Common versions
version.multiplatformSettings=0.8.1
version.koin=3.1.4
version.coroutines=1.5.2-native-mt

# Android versions
version.compose=1.0.5
version.composeNavigation=2.4.0-rc01
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure to import R class from your package example com.blabla.blablabla

Comment: @Denny, the R class is correctly imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denny Kurniawan's comment above pointed me in the right direction. I had a similar problem after changing the name of my project. At the top of your 'OnboardingScreen.kt' file, check to see if the full 'package' name matches your actual project's name, e.g. "package com.android.application".

If the package name listed in 'OnboardingScreen.kt' is not the same as your actual project's name, then the static R class is probably not being imported correctly and, hence, this error.

In other words, the full package name in 'OnboardingScreen.kt' should match the name of the folder shown under 'app->src->main->java'. Hope this helps someone as it did me.

Answer (score 19):

That's how you reference image resources:

```
import com.your.package.R 

val img = R.drawable.img_name
```

or

```
val img = com.your.package.R.drawable.img_name
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, this error happen because I drag my image to the resource manager, I solve it by importing the images manually with the "Import Drawables" button

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just change the `import androidx.compose.ui.R` to `import com.your.package.name.R` and boom~~~

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the `import androidx.compose.ui.R` to `import com.your.package.name.R` and it worked for me.